# How to write own XmlService-based ORM?

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework, orm

Here's an issue. There's an Oracle Database somewhere, but its inaccessible from software developers/users. Instead, we can use a xml-based webservice, which is a link between the program and a database, so it's like that:

1) I want to retrieve a table. I have a WebMethod for that. It returns plain xml of this table.

2) I want to add a row to a table. I have a WebMethod for that. It takes arguments it needs and  returns plain xml infirming whether the operation has succeeded or not.

So are comlplete SCUD(Select, create, update(im my case - just edit one), delete) interfaces for each entity stored in db. But there're relations overthere.

So i want to write some sort of wrapper to work with the whol database. Imagine there're tables are like:

```
Customers
*Id
 Name

Orders
*Id
 CustomerId
 OrderData
```

And i want to proceed such requests as:

```
var order = MYORM.GetOrders().First(); // first order
var customer = MYORM.GetOrders().First().Customer  // first order's customer

var customers  = MyORM.GetCustomers(); // returns customers list
```

BUT! 
`customers.Contains(customer)` must be `true`, even `customers` were requested and, therefore, instantiated after `customer`.

More, all create-delete-edit operations need to be supported too.

That's how EF works, but its mechanics seem to be too compex. Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: I think that the most appropriate would be to create an OData interface. You can build it very quickly, you can use EntityFramework behind it, and it's fairly easy to use. See here for a great tutorial: [Creating an OData API for StackOverflow including XML and JSON in 30 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Starting with SQL Server 2005 you can expose the database as a web service hosted inside sql server.

Comment: that's not even close to what i've asked ;)